# nodejs get request callback hitting multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

I am facing a problem, my get request's handler calling multiple times after a certain interval.

In the following example, if I call http://localhost:3000/test then it works perfectly fine but if I call http://localhost:3000 then it calls multiple times after a certain interval time. Someone please help me to understand what can be the issue with the task which takes long time and 'get' request.

```
var express = require('express');
var url = require('url');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
app.listen(3000);
console.log('App is listening on port: 3000');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log("req url = "+ req.url);

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('working in settimeout');
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('This is simple response.');
    }, 1000*15*60);

    console.log('set timeout registered.');
});

app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    console.log("req url = "+ req.url);
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('This is response for /test.');
});
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Exactely what happens multiple times?

Answer (score 2):

I have tested it with chrome and now I understand what you mean.
The browser, after waiting 120 seconds closes the connection and tries again.

This is why you see it multiple times, the request never finishes, since it is 900 seconds.

If you try with `curl`or something similar it will wait 900 seconds and you will see just one call.

Comment: OK, I think I got your point, but is there any way to solve this.

Comment: Browsers set a limit of 120 seconds, it is useless to wait more than 120 to load a webpage.

Comment: if you doing long process you can setTimeout false on express

Comment: I think I should go for web socket or ajax polling. By the way, thanks for your suggestions.